# How to change the alternate row color of Nautilus file manager in Ubuntu?

Tags: nautilus

I'm using the Nautilus file manager in Ubuntu and I want to change the alternate row color of the listed items. I'm using the Mojave-Dark theme, and I want to change the background color of the alternate rows to a different color. I tried modifying the gtk-dark.css file in the Mojave-Dark theme folder, but it didn't work. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458313/nautilus-alternate-row-color ?!

Comment: It is not a Nautilus issue but GTK. Gtk3.19 removed it and it never came back. Probably nobody can.

Comment: Aslında bu kod ile
```
.nautilus-list-view .view {
   background-color: purple;
}
```
When it comes to the listed items, I change their colors.

```
.nautilus-list-view  {
   background-color: red;
}

```
With this code, I change the background. But for some reason I cannot make alternative line color.

Comment: Try `alternate-row-color` in `gconf-editor`